# Wordpress - Blog Post Export With Caption HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a javascript developer but I was recently tasked with exporting some WordPress Blog Posts for a client. I thought it was going to be easy but I have ran into a problem that I don't know how to solve. I only know a *very small* bit of PHP and I'm not very familiar with WP. Hopefully I can find some help here?

When I did the export I got the data successfully, however, I still had the `[caption][/caption]` short code blocks in the blog post content.

Example:

```
[caption id="attachment_186704" align="alignnone" width="1024"]<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/img.jpg"><img class="size-large wp-image-186704" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/img.jpg" alt="Author name" width="1024" height="683" /></a> Author name with <a href="https://example.com/product/sol45mm/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Camera</a>[/caption]
```

On export I would like that replaced with the usual block of HTML that we see commonly on wordpress posts with images. Like in this image:
[image: WordPress example post with image]

I was trying the following but I think my syntax is wrong:

```
function update_caption($content) {
    return img_caption_shortcode('the_content_export', $content);
 }
 add_filter('the_content_export', 'update_caption', 999);
```

When I add that to *functions.php* and then run the export it wipes out the entire blog content field.

So, my goal is to fill in the caption short code block and I would also like to replace the line breaks with paragraph tags. I was able to figure out that latter request but I don't know how to do both in a single export.

Thanks for any help! And remember I'm a beginner with PHP but I have a few years of experience with javascript so I can read it and somewhat understand whats happening.